# Magento 2 on docker - no css loaded

Tags: php, css, magento, docker, magento2

I installed magento using composer:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

and load sample data.
It works pretty fine on localhost.

I created dockerfile and docker-compose for magento:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER xxxx

RUN apt-get -qqy update

RUN apt-get -qqy install apache2 \
        php \
        mysql-client \
        libapache2-mod-php \
        php-pear \
        php-mcrypt \
        php-gd \
        php-curl \
        php-mysql \
        php-dom \
        php-xml \
        php-xsl \
        php-mbstring \
        php-intl \
        php-zip \
        php-cli \
        php-cgi \
        curl \
        git \
        nano \
        vim \
        htop
RUN apt-get -qqy install nodejs npm
RUN apt-get -qqy install php-fpm

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

ADD ./20-mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
ADD ./20-mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini


RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY ./magento2.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.conf
#RUN rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

#COPY xdebug-enabler.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/

RUN php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"

COPY ./apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN a2enmod php7.0
RUN service apache2 restart


WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 9001
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

magento2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
       ServerName magento2test.localhost
       <Directory /var/www/html>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2.conf:

```
#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
    allowOverride  all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

and finaly docker-compose:

```
mageweb:
  build: docker-files/apache-xdebug
  command: rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
  command: apachectl -D FOREGROUND
  ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    - "80:80"
    - "9001:9001"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    -  ./project/:/var/www/html/
```

Now it is only one image cause im using remote mysql and I will add more images later.

Anyway I'm able to build and up docker.
I'm able to install and setup magento.
Of course I tried flush all cache, and done all of those comands (using docker exec -it container_name bash:

```
php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
php bin/magento module:enable --all
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

But style.css and some js are not loading property:
https://postimg.org/image/wla49rvrz/

system.log:

```
[2016-11-17 07:27:39] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_2ae0e2a835d549823c9720ea0833000d3 and handles default, catalog_category_view, catalog_category_view_type_default, catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children, catalog_category_view_id_39: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-11-17 07:27:39] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_2a7ccd8094436548b564a588f6303121c and handles 2columns-left: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-11-17 07:27:40] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_26f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

When Im trying change permissions for project on docker container it won't apply.
May it happend because of Windows?

Do You have any ideas hot can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

There is my Dockerfile for Apache/php:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER Konrad Siamro

RUN apt-get -qqy update

RUN apt-get -qqy install apache2 \
        php \
        mysql-client \
        libapache2-mod-php \
        php-pear \
        php-mcrypt \
        php-gd \
        php-curl \
        php-mysql \
        php-dom \
        php-xml \
        php-xsl \
        php-mbstring \
        php-intl \
        php-zip \
        php-cli \
        php-cgi \
        curl \
        git \
        nano \
        vim \
        htop

RUN apt-get -qqy install php-soap

RUN apt-get -qqy install bindfs \
    dos2unix \
    php-xdebug

RUN apt-get -qqy install nodejs npm
RUN apt-get -qqy install php-fpm

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY ./20-mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
COPY ./20-mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini

RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY ./magento2.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.conf
#RUN rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

COPY ./xdebug-enabler.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
COPY ./auth.json /var/www/auth.json

RUN php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"

COPY ./apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN a2enmod php7.0

RUN echo "extension=php_openssl.dll" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

RUN service apache2 restart

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ./ssh /var/ssh

EXPOSE 9001
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY ./start_safe_perms.sh /usr/local/bin/start_safe_perms.sh
RUN dos2unix /usr/local/bin/start_safe_perms.sh
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/start_safe_perms.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/usr/local/bin/start_safe_perms.sh"]
```

and apache2 conf:

```
# this is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
    allowOverride  all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>



# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my Dockerfile support PHP-FMP:

```
FROM php:7.4.20-fpm

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=2.1.3

# Locales
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y locales

RUN dpkg-reconfigure locales \
    && locale-gen C.UTF-8 \
    && /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8

RUN echo 'en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8' >> /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen

ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8

# Common
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        openssl \
        git \
        gnupg2 \
        vim \
        telnet \
        cron

# Install php extension

# intl
RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl

# xml
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        dom \
        xmlrpc \
        xsl \
        simplexml

# images
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        gd \
        exif

# database
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
    mysqli \
    pdo \
    pdo_mysql

# strings
RUN apt-get install -y libonig-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
    gettext \
    mbstring

# math
RUN apt-get install -y libgmp-dev \
    && ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h /usr/include/gmp.h \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        gmp \
        bcmath

# compression
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libbz2-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        zip \
        bz2

# memcached
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libmemcached11

# curl
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libcurl4 \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) curl

# images
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        gd \
        exif

# others
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
    soap \
    sockets \
    calendar \
    sysvmsg \
    sysvsem \
    sysvshm \
    ctype \
    iconv

# Install form source

# ext-apcu
ENV EXT_APCU_VERSION=5.1.17

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/apcu \
    && curl -fsSL https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/archive/v$EXT_APCU_VERSION.tar.gz | tar xvz -C /usr/src/php/ext/apcu --strip 1 \
    && docker-php-ext-install apcu \
    && echo "[apcu]" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-apcu.ini \
    && echo "apc.enabled=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-apcu.ini

# ext-opache
RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
    && echo "zend_extension=opcache" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini \
    && echo "opcache.enable=1" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini \
    && echo "opcache.enable_cli=0" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini \
    && echo "opcache.memory_consumption=356" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini \
    && echo "opcache.max_accelerated_files=100000" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini \
    && echo "opcache.validate_timestamps=0" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini

# x-debug
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.0.4 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=xdebug" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=debug,develop" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9003" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.discover_client_host=true" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /tmp/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

# clean up
RUN docker-php-source delete

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
    echo 'memory_limit = 2G' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini

# Add user
RUN groupadd -g 1000 app \
    && useradd -g 1000 -u 1000 -d /var/www -s /bin/bash app

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html \
    && chown -R app:app /var/www

USER app:app
VOLUME /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

So It's my repository, check it out!

https://github.com/dylanops/docker-magento

Comment: Hey, it is a quite old topic :) but thanks for Your solution. Right now I am working with DDEV instead of Docker `directly`. I can definitely recommend that solution for You too